# Schengen visa application

Tags: visas, schengen, italy, visa-refusals, uae

I am a Srilankan residing in UAE for past 10 years. My family was in UAE for past 9/10 years. Now they are back in UAE on residence visa while I have continued my stay in UAE.

1.If the UAE residence visa has been stamped only 15 days ago for my family members can I still apply for Schengen visas for them?

Comment: This question contains so many circumstance-specific details that it borders upon regulated legal advice. It means any answers will address a unique combination of details that are unlikely to have enduring value for others. Also some of the sub-questions will rely solely upon opinion.   We're not a legal advice forum, so I am placing this question in the queue as 'too broad'.

Comment: -1 until the question is edited into a suitable and answerable state.

Comment: John, you might do well to split this up into several questions. The site's design encourages focused questions where it is more likely to find a single answer to "accept" as the best one. This also makes it easier to pose questions that would be useful to future readers, another goal of the site. Also, if they decide to refuse your visa application, there's no "rejection stamp," they just return the passport without a visa in it.

Comment: Thank you Gayout and Phog. I will redo them and post individually.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will try to help you the best that I can, from my knowledge of the visa process and having successfully applied twice. However there are many circumstances that affect the visa process, and some countries are more accepting than others.

> 1.I have the NOC from the present employer (for 10 days leave), though I have just completed 3 months. Would this short tenure be a concern
>   when processing our applications?

No, it will not. People move jobs all the time. Remember that you have to convince the embassy that you are a genuine temporary visitor, and not trying to immigrate.

> 2.My family UAE residence visas were stamped only 15 days ago. (Please note kids were born in UAE and past 9/10 years they all were living in
>   UAE). Since the new residence visa was just stamped, will it have a
>   negative impact by the time of processing our applications?

No, this has no impact. Again, residencies are renewed all the time.

> 3.Five years ago when I was with the previous employer, I was assigned in Afghanistan where I stayed for 4 months, solely for logistics
>   functions and coordination with the U.S. military. So Afghan visa has
>   been stamped on my (previous) passport. How can this affect my
>   application?

It has no bearing (I was in Iraq for a similar logistics client).

> 4.Should I submit the previous passport too along with the application?

Only if you are specifically asked for it, or only if it contains a valid visa. Otherwise your old passport is not relevant.

> 5.Does it require to mention the above point No 3 on the cover letter or not required?

There is no cover letter required for a Schengen application.  The requirements are:

1. Valid passport
2. Valid residency
3. Valid travel insurance for the length of your stay, with minimum of EUR 30,000 coverage per person.
4. Proof of funds to support yourself on your trip, or if your trip is sponsored, evidence of sponsorship.
5. Filled in application.
6. Photos.
7. Hotel reservation, for the dates of intended travel.
8. Flight reservation, for the dates of intended travel.
9. Your itinerary (for example, if you are traveling to more than one country).
10. Ties to the country (this can be evidenced by a employment letter, property papers, family ties, etc.)

> 6.If required to be, I can get a letter from the previous employer. Is it advisable to get the said letter and attach it along with the
>   application?

No, what would the relevance be? There is nothing that your previous provider can furnish.

> 7.How much of bank balance would be considered as a healthy limit for a family of 5? (Planing to travel to Rome and Venice for a total of 10
>   days)

Each country in the Schengen zone has its own minimum requirements. [This PDF (in Italian)](http://vistoperitalia.esteri.it/Moduli/it/Direttiva_MinInterno_1-3-2000.pdf) has a table that lists the fund requirements for visitors to Italy.

It states the following **minimum amounts** as translated from the PDF using my very rusty Italian:

1. For a visit between 1 to 5 days, 269.50 EUR per person (for one person), 212.81 EUR for 2 - 5 people - fixed amount.
2. For a visit of 6 to 10 days, 44.93 EUR per person (1 person) / 26.33 EUR (multiple people) each day.
3. 11 - 20 days; 51.64 EUR (fixed) + 36.67 EUR (each day) (1 person) / 25.82 (fixed) + 22.21 EUR (each day) (2 - 5 people)
4. 20+ days; 206.58 (fixed) + 27.89 (each day) (1 person) / 118.79 (fixed) + 17.04 EUR (per day) (2 - 5 person)

Please do not **park funds in your account**. This will almost certainly get your application rejected as its considered a form of fraud.

> 8.In case if a visa is rejected will the Italian consulate straightaway endorse the rejection stamp on the passports or, they
>   will call us for an interview to discuss further and then decide to
>   approve or reject?

No, there is no such process. Either you are approved, or you are rejected. If they have any questions about your documents; they may ask for additional details (this is usually a good sign).

Comment: Dear Burhan..One travel agent mentioned having a stamp from a war zone will have a negative impact. That is why I was worried. Where as in my case it was solely a business trip and based there for 4 months and to prove that I thought of getting a letter if it required. Since you too have worked in Iraq I am sure you too understand the situation well. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Previous travel history does have an impact. For example, if this is your first ever trip anywhere outside of your country, then this raises many flags. If you are a seasoned traveler with a good travel history, then this positively affects your application. However, I have not heard from anyone that for Schengen zone, a stamp from a "war zone" (which, by does not apply to Afghanistan in any way) has an impact - this would only be the case if you were trying to claim asylum. I traveled to Iraq under military escort and it didn't affect my chances.

Comment: Makes sense. No. this is not the first time out of UAE but the first time to Schengen. This is a vacation plan which I promised my kids last year and postponed. I will discuss further with the travel agent before I apply. Just trying to avoid any rejection or reapplying charges and the hassle you have to go through. .